# Someone point my website with his domain, how can I block?

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

the sorgarden.se domain is pointing to my server. I have lost SEO ranking for duplicate contents...

how can i block this? from htaccess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Virtual host in apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
  DocumentRoot "/www/docs/example.com"
  ServerName host.example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com
  ServerAlias example.com
  ErrorLog "logs/example.com-error_log"
  TransferLog "logs/example.com-access_log"
</VirtualHost>
```

That way, client can only get content if they request example.com and not something.se.